# How to make an input not case sensitive

Tags: javascript, input

I want to know how make it when the user types in something to an input it doesn't have to be the same capitalization as the value for the `document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters";` to appear.

**HTML**

```
<input id="ask" type="text"
       placeholder = "Ex: how tall is the Gateway Arch"
       onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
       onblur="this.placeholder = 'Ex: how tall is the gateway arch'"
       text-align: center/>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("ask").innerHTML == "how tall are the pyramids") {
        document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters";
    } else if (document.getElementById("ask").value == "how tall is the gateway arch") {
        document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "630 feet";
    } else if (document.getElementById("ask").value == "how tall is the empire state building") {
        document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "1,454 feet";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, use `value` instead of `innerHTML` for input fields

**Second**, convert both side **lowercase** or **uppercase** during comparing

Try like this

```
var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase();
if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids")
```

Or like this

```
var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toUpperCase();
if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids".toUpperCase())
```

Comment: That only will work for on if else statement not the others

Comment: assign it one variable use that variable everywhere you need to instead of using `document.getElementById("ask").value` everytime

Comment: this is a dumb question but how would you assign it one variable

Comment: `var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase(); ` use ask everywhere you need